# How to make this Views completely responsive in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have this text views:

[image: Items]

I'm using a linear layout, with a weightSum of 4 to put the TextViews inside, but as you can see, the `options` one has no margin with the right side of the screen, which makes it look pretty bad. And if I add some margin, the view gets bigger in height, which makes it look bigger than the other views in smaller screens, how could I fix it?

Here is my XML :

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_constrast_top"
      android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
      android:paddingStart="12dp"
      android:paddingTop="12dp"
      android:paddingEnd="12dp"
      android:text="@string/moves"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/app_color_light"
      android:textSize="16sp" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_constrast_bot"
      android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
      android:paddingLeft="18dp"
      android:paddingRight="12dp"
      android:paddingBottom="12dp"
      android:text="1"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/app_color_light"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_moves_top"
      android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
      android:paddingLeft="8dp"
      android:paddingTop="12dp"
      android:paddingRight="8dp"
      android:text="@string/options"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/app_color_light"
      android:textSize="16sp" />
   <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:background="@color/contrast_data" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_moves_bot"
      android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
      android:paddingLeft="18dp"
      android:paddingRight="12dp"
      android:paddingBottom="6dp"
      android:text="0"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/app_color_light"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please give the complete xml code, so that this can be checked. This code is somewhat incomplete I guess

Answer (score 0):

put them all in a LinearLayout and set layout_marginLeft layout_marginRight so  they all can have uniformed margins.